# Proper Way to Mimick UITextField Placeholder Color

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have another object that I want to have the same color as the UITextField's default placeholder text color.

I know I can simply make a new UIColor with the same color, but this seems hacky and problematic if Apple changes the default UITextField color. I instead am looking for the proper way to access the UITextField color so that I can set another field to the same color?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From `UITextField` API in `UIKit`, the place holder color of `UITextField` is `70% of gray color` and it is defined by the `iOS SDK`.

```
open var placeholder: String? // default is nil. string is drawn 70% gray
```

From Apple Doc.s

> The placeholder string is drawn using a system-defined color.

Probably, we may not have an access to these system defined colors with any attributes given in `iOS SDK`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
```

Now in viewDidLoad method:-

```
let placeHolederText = "PlaceHolder"
let attributedPlaceHolder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolederText, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red ,NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12) ])
self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceHolder
self.textField.borderStyle = .bezel
self.textField.tintColor = .gray
```

Result:-

[image]

I hope this will help you,
Thanks.